# ctx.req is undefined Next.js

Tags: next.js

ctx.req is undefined Next.js. This code is inside _document.js file.

```js
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const props = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
        const userData = await getServerSideToken(ctx.req);
        return { ...userData, ...props }
    }
```

I am trying to pass ctx.req to getServerSideToken, but it is displaying an error saying that ctx.req is undefined

Answer (score 1):

To make `ctx.req` contain the expected payload, you must invoke `getServerSideProps` further down the Next.js tree, for example, in `pages/index.js`. Then `ctx.req` in `_document` will no longer be `undefined`.

I don't understand so many people complaining about application logic in this file. This is literally where you need to access server-side cookies and add a classname or two to the `body` element. Same for other css-in-js logic as well.

Comment: _"I don't understand so many people complaining about application logic in this file"_ - the use cases you mention are completely valid reasons to do so. I've removed my comment on the original question.